# Unreal Engine Packaging

Tags: unreal-engine4, packaging, unreal-engine5

Is it possible to package an unreal engine project into one file? Instead of having many other dependency's with the exe after packaging. Obviously this isn't a necessity, but it'd be cool if it's possible!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far i know it is not possible to build one single file from editor, but the project itself is already packed in a .pak file, so I don't understand clearly what you are asking.

- If you want a single exe file to distribute your project, you can achieve this by using innoSetup to create a .exe that install "WindowsNoEditor" folder content. By doing this your app will be listed in windows list.

Here's the documentation btw https://jrsoftware.org/isdl.php

Answer (score 1):

You could, always create a portable launcher, with a downloader that downloads the needed files, or... you can package it with an installer software with everything to run the exe.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32121455)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to package as one file. As for the dependencies, if they're not on your system, the program will let the user know and download and install them for you automatically, so it's not really an issue.